# How do I personalize Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, nexus-7, phone

I installed Ubuntu Touch today on my Nexus 7 (grouper nakasi) and I appear to be logged in as somebody else - a developer perhaps. I have their Facebook notifications, music they like, people they know, missed calls, etc. Seems a little weird. Is this not ready to be personalized yet? I can't find any kind of settings page to do something like a factory reset.

Comment: You know what happens when you assume, right? I saw quite a few demos but didn't see anything that mentioned they contained the profiles of the engineering team. Apparently I missed that one.

Comment: It's dummy data so you can get a preview of the "look and feel " http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/ubuntu-touch-developer-preview-coming-tomorrow-heres-why-you-shouldnt-get-too-excited notice even some apps are "dummy" apps. So yes this is for developers and not personal use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much in the way of personalisation can be done yet, but if you wish you can [get rid of the inbuilt contacts](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#Sample_content).